Is this the proper way of doing set_difference in C++?
I'm translating some old Julia code to C++, and as a newcomer to C++, I find myself leaning towards using many of its new features, perhaps even when they're not necessary. Currently, this line creating some problems:
insertable = setdiff(route.vertices, 1:route.data.dimension)
What I came up with on the C++ side was:
Route route_cpy = route;
std::sort(route_cpy.vertices.begin(), route_cpy.vertices.end(), [](int a, int b) { return a < b; });
std::vector<int> all_vertices(data.vertices.size()); std::iota(all_vertices.begin(), all_vertices.end(), 0);
std::vector<int> insertable;
std::set_difference(all_vertices.begin(), all_vertices.end(), route_cpy.vertices.begin(), route_cpy.vertices.end(),
    std::back_inserter(insertable));

Notice that I had to copy the route object just to sort its vertices before performing the set_difference. Is all of this necessary? Would it be better to create a set containing values from 1 through data.vertices.size() and then remove the values present in route.vertices()?

Someone asked a similar question recently, and I showed them: https://godbolt.org/z/MbG5cMh87

So the question is what approach has better time complexity. Let's analyze it for each case (let the size of route.vertices be n, size of all_vertices be m):

Using std::vector, std::sort and std::set_difference
Firstly, you are copying std::vector, the complexity of this is O(n). Then you are sorting it with complexity O(n * log n). Then std::set_difference is used, it has linear time complexity or O(n + m) (because this function needs to iterate through both arrays). So, after adding we will get:
O(n + n * log n + n + m) = O(n * (log n + 2) + m) = O(n * log(3n) + m). Also note that std::vector uses cache quite effectively.

Using std::set, std::set::erase. Time complexity of constructing std::set from std::vector is O(n * log n). Then, you need to erase elements (or try to erase, if they are not in this set) m times, each of this operations will cost O(m * log n). So the total time complexity is: O(n * log n + m * log n) = O((n + m) * log n). Also std::set doesn't allocate memory as efficiently as std::vector does.


As a conclusion, usage of std::vector is better in this case. Don't worry about using algorithms from the standard library, they're usually faster than manual implementation.
But there is even more effective way to implement this in your case using for loop to iterate through route_cpy and add to the insertable values between every two elements of route_cpy, time complexity is O(n * log(2n) + m) and no additional memory is used for all_vertices array (and copying not the whole route, but only route.vertices, and I didn't count initialization of all_vertices and std::iota complexity in previous cases, which adds O(2m), and the following approach doesn't even use additional array as a range):
auto copy_vertices = route.vertices;
std::sort(copy_vertices.begin(), copy_vertices.end());
std::vector<int> insertable;
for (int i = 0; i < copy_vertices[0]; i++)
{
    insertable.push_back(i);
}
for (int i = 1; i < copy_vertices.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = copy_vertices[i-1] + 1; j < copy_vertices[i]; j++)
    {
        insertable.push_back(j);
    }
}
for (int i = copy_vertices.back() + 1; i < data.vertices.size(); i++)
{
    insertable.push_back(i);
}

